# Make hibernate entity dirty if depending entity gets dirty

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity Person with optimistic lock mechanism. A Person has several Fingers. I want the optimistic lock counter of the Person count up if any of its fingers changes.

```
@Test
public void testVersionUpOnChildChange() throws Exception {
    // persist entities => version is initially created
    doInTransaction(new HibernateMethod() {
        @Override
        public void run(Session session) {
            michael = new Person("Michael");
            michael.setId(1);
            michael.addFinger(new Finger("Thumb", michael));
            michael.addFinger(new Finger("Ringfinger", michael));
            michael.addFinger(new Finger("Index", michael));
            session.persist(michael);
        }
    });
    Assert.assertEquals(0, michael.getVersion().intValue());

    // just read michael from database => michaels version counter should stay as it is
    doInTransaction(new HibernateMethod() {
        @Override
        public void run(Session session) {
            michael = (Person) session.get(Person.class, 1);
            session.update(michael);
        }
    });
    Assert.assertEquals(0, michael.getVersion().intValue());

    // do changes to michael directly => version counter goes up
    doInTransaction(new HibernateMethod() {
        @Override
        public void run(Session session) {
            michael = (Person) session.get(Person.class, 1);
            michael.setName("Der Bulla");
            session.update(michael);
        }
    });
    Assert.assertEquals(1, michael.getVersion().intValue());


    // add a new finger to michael => version counter goes up
    doInTransaction(new HibernateMethod() {
        @Override
        public void run(Session session) {
            michael = (Person) session.get(Person.class, 1);
            Finger finger = new Finger("Small finger", michael);
            michael.addFinger(finger);
            session.update(michael);
        }
    });
    Assert.assertEquals(2, michael.getVersion().intValue());

    // here's the tricky part: change a finger of michael without any changes to michael itself => version counter goes up
    doInTransaction(new HibernateMethod() {
        @Override
        public void run(Session session) {
            michael = (Person) session.get(Person.class, 1);
            Assert.assertEquals(michael.getFingers().size(), 4);
            Finger anyFinger = michael.getFingers().iterator().next();
            anyFinger.setName("Middlefinger");
            session.update(anyFinger);
        }
    });
    Assert.assertEquals(3, michael.getVersion().intValue());
}
```

`Assert.assertEquals(3, michael.getVersion().intValue());` fails because Hibernate doen't care to update the versioncounter of a person if a depending finger changes. Can I persudade Hibernate to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If I good understood your question than maybe the solution you is looking for could be

```
  @OptimisticLock(excluded=true)
```

Just put this annotation onto your List of fingers collection. Hopefully I understood correctly your question.

Comment: No, mostly of all I want the opposite. Version should not only be incremented if the collection itself changes, but even if a member of the collectino changes. I updated my questiion a little.

Comment: I know that this is not the answer you are waiting for, but in your case i would save the Person and will put @Cascade on the list of fingers. Because if you are saving the fingers independently its no way to force hibernate to recognize this update on the parent (Person) - at least as far as i know. Try to think about the approach to have a model where the Person is a parent and saving in cascade all of his childs. (collection of fingers)